# git diff - show only the changes, nothing "near" the change

Tags: git, git-diff

I'd like

`git diff`

to only display the differences, nothing "near" my changes.

How can I do this?

Comment: Leaving this hear as it allows this to be found by searching for "near"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the git docs don't use the word "near". They use "context" instead, so

```
git diff -U0
```

means display 0 lines of context around your diffs, as described in the `git-diff` man page:

> -U, --unified=
>              Generate diffs with  lines of context instead of the usual three. Implies

Comment: Did you ask a question then answer it yourself 2 seconds later?

Comment: It's actually encouraged by SO to post and answer your own question if it is not already on SO and you found the answer. There is even a checkbox to directly add an answer when posting a question. See [its ok to ask and answer your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Yeah the reason I put the question here is because when I google around for it, I didn't find an answer. It was clearly there in the docs once I read them carefully. I was just searching for the word "near", but should've been looking for "context" when googling.